# Most efficient way to join two object arrays

Tags: java, arrays, performance, object, merge

This object is what it is all about:

```
public class Unit {

private String label;
NumberRow numberRow;

Unit(String label){
    this.label=label;
    numberRow = new NumberRow();
}

....

}
```

It contains a label name and an Array of doubles (thats the NumberRow())
Another class named UnitRow is an array of those Units:

```
public class UnitRow {

Unit[] unitArray;
private int elementsInArray;
Scanner in;


UnitRow(){
    unitArray = new Unit[Dataset.numberOfRecords];
    elementsInArray = 0;
}
......

}
```

Yet I am going to introduce another class: Leaf. It contains a unit and implements the cluster interface:

```
public class Leaf implements Cluster {

private Unit unit;

Leaf(Unit unit){
    this.unit = unit;
}

    .......
public UnitRow getUnits() {
    UnitRow unitRow = new UnitRow();
    unitRow.addLabel(unit.getLabel());
    for (int x = 0; x < Dataset.numberOfVariables; x++){
        unitRow.addVar(unit.valueOnIndex(x));
    }
    return unitRow;
}

public boolean hasChildren() {
    return false;
}

}
```

It contains a Unit and in the function UnitRow a new UnitRow is created with only one Unit; namely the Unit that was given when created when the class was created.
Another Class (last one) called Node also implementing the cluster interface:

```
public class Node implements Cluster{

private Cluster leftChild;
private Cluster rightChild;

Node(Cluster leftChild, Cluster rightChild){
    this.leftChild = leftChild;
    this.rightChild = rightChild;
}

public UnitRow getUnits() {
    return leftChild.getUnits() + rightChild.getUnits();
}

}
```

A node has a left child and a right child. Such a child can either be a leaf or another node. 
Now I have a function in Node giving me an array of units from all the leafs below itself.
I tought I'd tell java: return leftChild.getUnits() + rightChild.getUnits(); so e.g. if the leftChild and the rightChild are both leafs those arrays they will return are added together in that statement. However, this is not the right way. What is the most efficient way to let the function getUnits in Node return one array with Units in the most efficient way?

Comment: Consider using `List`s instead (such as `ArrayList`). With a `List` you can call `addAll`.

Comment: I wish I could, but the University won't let me do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine two arrays:

```
public UnitRow getUnits() {
    Unit[] array1and2 = new int[leftChild.getUnits().length + rightChild.getUnits().length];
    System.arraycopy(leftChild.getUnits(), 0, array1and2, 0, leftChild.getUnits().length);
    System.arraycopy(rightChild.getUnits(), 0, array1and2, leftChild.getUnits().length, rightChild.getUnits().length);
    return new UnitRow(array1and2); //add this constructor
}
```

Or, the loop way:

```
public UnitRow getUnits() {
    Unit[] array1and2 = new int[leftChild.getUnits().length + rightChild.getUnits().length];

    for (int i=0; i<leftChild.getUnits().length; i++) {
        array1and2[i]= leftChild.getUnits()[i];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<rightChild.getUnits().length; i++) {
        array1and2[leftChild.getUnits().length + i]= rightChild.getUnits()[i];
    }

    return new UnitRow(array1and2); //add this constructor
}
```

Comment: Yes this is certainly a good solution, but you create a new array for every node it passes. Is this necessary?